# How to save the value of an input for a function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP and SQL and JQUERY/JS. I'm trying to make is so that when a person press's enter(while in an input field) the same thing occurs as if they hit the existing button.

This is the original button code:

```
$(document).on("click", '.submit', function(event) { 
  var to_user_id = $(this).attr('id');
  to_user_id = to_user_id.replace(/chatButton/g, "");
  sendMessage(to_user_id);
});
```

My Attempt at making it so that enter did the same thing as the above code:

```js
$('#chatMessage3').keyup(function(e) {  
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {   
    var to_user_id = $(this).attr('id');

  sendMessage(to_user_id);  
}
```

Comment: Question, do you have it?

Comment: It seems like you do that, except for the `to_user_id = to_user_id.replace(/chatButton/g, "");` line.

Comment: And also I suppose `$('#chatMessage3')` must have `id` attribute which is the same as with `.submit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your submit buttons have IDs like `chatButton1`, `chatButton2`, etc. and you want to just send `1`, `2`. You need to do a similar replacement in the `#chatMessage3` handler:

```
$('#chatMessage3').keyup(function(e) {  
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {   
    var to_user_id = $(this).attr('id');
    to_user_id = to_user_id.replace(/chatMessage/, '');
    sendMessage(to_user_id);  
}
```